# append string after pattern match in solaris with sed

Tags: bash, sed, solaris

how can I add a new row after a search? in solaris
I tried it but it doesn't work

```
 sed 's/user.emerg/test/a\' file
```

I want add new line after 
user.emerg                                      *

```
#
# non-loghost machines will use the following lines to cause "user"
# log messages to be logged locally.
#
ifdef(`LOGHOST', ,
user.err                                        /dev/sysmsg
user.err                                        /var/adm/messages
user.alert                                      `root, operator'
user.emerg                                      *
)
```

thanks

Comment: could you please show us part of the input file and desired output?

Comment: i want add something after user.emerg                                      *
# non-loghost machines will use the following lines to cause "user"
# log messages to be logged locally.
#
ifdef(`LOGHOST', ,
user.err                                        /dev/sysmsg
user.err                                        /var/adm/messages
user.alert                                      `root, operator'
user.emerg                                      *
)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/user.emerg/G' file
```

This appends the empty hold space following a match on `user.emerg`.

If you want to add something into that appended line, use:

```
sed '/user.emerg/{x;s/^/add something /;x;G}' file
```

or perhaps more easily:

```
sed '/user.emerg/a\add something ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available or an alternative.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '/^user.emerg/a' "" . ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

but `*csh` shells does not like that syntax, you can create an `ed` script.

Using an `ed` script.

```
cat script.ed
```

Output

```sh
/^user.emerg/a

.
,p
Q
```

Then

```sh
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

If you think the output is correct, or if you want to edit the file in-place, change

```
,p
Q
```

to

```
w
q
```